# aws Dynamodb get multiple items by partition key in aws management console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Can I get multiple items by partition key in aws management console for Ddynamodb without using BatchGetItem. My Partition key is abcd1 abcd1 abcd2.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this within the DynamoDB web UI because a Query which is used can only retrieve a single item collection, but you can achieve it using the PartiQL editor using SQL language.

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pk IN ['abc1','abc2']`

You will need to modify the statement to suit your specific needs

Comment: Hi lee, I will query this query in aws Athena?

Comment: No, if you look on the DynamoDB web console you will see on the left panel `PartiQL` editor, it will allow you to execute SQL like statements against your items.

Comment: Hi Lee, Thanks, I will make it as a solution. Question: Can I sue wildcard is PartiQL: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pk like %abcd%